# How to have colors in vim when :syntax on does nothing?

Tags: vim, terminal, centos, color-scheme

Logged as root on a CentOS 5.3, I can't have colors in vim (7.0.237, minimal, common and enhanced rpms), even with :syntax on ...
I can display colors with other commands, so I have colors (I don't know how many !)

Any clue ?

Thanks.

Comment: what's the output of `:scriptnames` and `:filetype` after having loaded your file?

Comment: Nothing ! 

I launched vim (`[root@hostname ~] vim`), then typed rour commands, and nothing appeared ...

Comment: so, what does `:version` and `:echo $VIM`, `:echo $VIMRUNTIME` tell?

Comment: :version
    VIM - Vi IMproved 7.0 (2006 May 7, compiled Sep 19 2009 17:22:51)
    Included patches: 1, 3-4, 7-9, 11, 13-17, 19-26, 29-31, 34-44, 47, 50-56, 58-64, 66-73, 75, 77-92, 94-107, 109, 202, 234-237
    Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com> (...)

Comment: `Tiny version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
    -arabic -autocmd -balloon_eval -browse +builtin_terms -byte_offset -cindent -clientserver -clipboard -cmdline_compl -cmdline_hist -cmdline_info -comments 
    -cryptv -cscope -cursorshape -dialog -diff -digraphs -dnd -ebcdic -emacs_tags -eval -ex_extra -extra_search -farsi -file_in_path -find_in_path -folding 
    -footer +fork() -gettext (...) -syntax `

Comment: (Sorry for formatting !) Ho you got it I think : `-syntax`

Comment: `:echo $VIM` and `:echo $VIMRUNTIME` return nothing

Comment: So vim's RPM for CentOS doesn't include syntax lib ? I have no other choice than compile it myself ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CentOS comes with a "tiny" version of Vim installed which has limited features.

You'll have to install the "enhanced" package if you want all of the good stuff.

```
yum install vim-enhanced
```

At least that was what I had to do with CentOS 5.

To list all of the Vim packages:

```
 yum list vim*
```

There should be an enhanced version there (hopefully).

Comment: vim-common.x86_64                                                        2:7.0.109-4.el5_2.4z                                                       installed
vim-enhanced.x86_64                                                      2:7.0.109-4.el5_2.4z       installed
vim-minimal.x86_64         2:7.0.109-6.el5                                                            installedAvailable Packages
vim-X11.x86_64                                                           2:7.0.109-4.el5_2.4z                                                       CENTOS

Comment: vim-common.x86_64    2:7.0.109-4.el5_2.4z installed
vim-enhanced.x86_64  2:7.0.109-4.el5_2.4z installed
vim-minimal.x86_64   2:7.0.109-6.el5      installed
Available Packages
vim-X11.x86_64       2:7.0.109-4.el5_2.4z CENTOS

Comment: SHould have a "preview" button for responses ! Sorry for formatting !

Comment: @Erwan: I missed that in your original post.  Your comment that `:version` reports "Tiny version" shows that the enhanced version is not getting ran; it should be reporting "Huge version".  On my box, `vi` runs the tiny version while `vim` runs the enhanced version.

Comment: Ha ha ha
ls -l `which vim`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Aug 18 10:44 /bin/vim -> /bin/vi

I'll find the guilty, I promise ! :-)

I have opened the vim-enhanced rpm and it puts executable in /usr/bin/vim, and this executable is OK.

Thank you guys !

Answer (score 1):

How do you start Vim, with vim or with vi.

If started with vi win often uses a safe mode that disables many features to make it safe for administrative use.

If so, try vim instead.

Comment: Some distros map `vi` to `vim -C` to provide the vi compability. As original vi didn't have the bells and whistles, it feels rather limited after some Vim usage.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have a syntax definition file for the type of file you are editing.  What kind of file is it?  Try forcing a particular syntax format with

```
:set syntax=<format>
```

So, if you're editing XML, try

```
:set syntax=xml
```

Comment: It is bash. I tried `:set syntax=sh` and `:set syntax=bash`, and I get nothing : no error, no message.

Comment: Maybe I have no syntax scripts at all ?

Answer (score 0):

If you've already installed **vim-enhanced**, then check your PATH. Chances are good that `/usr/bin` isn't there.

The `vi` in `/bin` is the limited-feature "tiny" version of vim. If you look in `/usr/bin`, you'll find the "huge" version (as `vim`, not `vi`).